# What disc image formats does Windows 7 Disc Image Burner support?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, dvd, burning

I've discovered that Windows 7 comes with ISO burning ability built right into Windows Explorer. It's a great addition, but I was wondering if Windows 7 supports any other formats. For example: `.ccd`, `.dvd`, `.img`, `.udf`, or `.bin`.

Also, does it support dual-layer disc images?

I've looked through Microsoft's documentation and I can't find a simple answer anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Windows 7 Disc Image Burner only supports `.iso` and `.img` image formats, from this page on Technet:

> [Burn a Disc Image from an ISO or IMG file in Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd451080.aspx)

Another source that says the same thing (only `.iso` and `.img` are supported):

> [How to Burn a Disc Image from a ISO or IMG file in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/548-burn-disc-image-iso-img-file.html)

As for dual-layer disc image support, [check out this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/548-burn-disc-image-iso-img-file-3.html), it looks like it might - worth a try...

Comment: Thanks. Shame there's nothing conclusive on dual-layer burning. My tests seem to indicate that you're right about ISO and IMG files, though.